# Android Studio runs bluestacks emulator but does not come up in android device manager?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I'm doing a project in Android studio. I'm using Bluestacks as an emulator. The app works perfectly fine and the connection is working as the app runs on Bluestacks. The problem is when I run the Android Device Monitor, it doesn't show my emulator or the name I saved my project as. It just shows the default emulator.   What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps consider Genymotion as an alternative.  GenyMotion works with ADM. In some ways it's better than a real device as you can access App Data through ADM.

Comment: Thank you I will try that but it's abit strange he way it won't connect to the android device monitor. I can't even open the data file in the default emulator??

Comment: You could also try starting the emulator before Android Studio and also vice-versa.  When I first got Genymotion starting before AS was most successful. More recently, changes to the SDK tools made me have to reverse this and have ADM or the run dialog where it allows you to select the device open. More recently Genymotion and AS seem much better. I  find it best to start Genymotion first, when CPU use is low (I start devices from Genymotion) I also find it better to wait for a while after starting Genymotion before starting a device.

Comment: Okay thanks very much I will try download genymotion tonight and see if that works. Do I need to also download virtualbox for this to run or will that automatically download and install when i download it??

Comment: You certainly need virtual box. I can't remember if it comes with it though.

Comment: thanks i will let you know how I get on

Comment: I tried to download genymotion but the player ade stops working every time I start the virtual device is there any alternatives?

Comment: I've only ever used GenyMotion. So I'm not at all sure.

Comment: happy days I got it working thanks for everything Mike